# How to assign table name for dataset tables

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I create three stored procedure in MySQL. It's working fine. Now I read the third procedure using C#. It returns the two tables named table, table1. How can I assign name of the each tables? I'm really confused the tables name while using more than 8 or 10.

```
create procedure dbo.GetPeople
as
begin
    select * from dbo.Person;
end;

create procedure dbo.GetCars
as
begin
    select * from dbo.Car;
end;

-- This gives the same result as before
create procedure dbo.GetSomething
as
begin
    exec dbo.GetPeople;
    exec dbo.GetCars;
end;
```

Comment: where is your c# code? Can you share your c# code?

Answer (score 0):

In c# you you will get table from dataSet by index, because when we fill a dataSet from a dataBase then we never recieve table names from db.

One thing is passible as i used for reporting when i returning multiple tables by sp is that:

select an extra colum in each select statement that reprent table name.

e.g
your sp

```
create procedure dbo.GetData
as
begin

select '' as 'Person', * from dbo.Person;
select '' as 'Car',* from dbo.Car;

end;
```

And do foreach loop on you dataSet to get firstColumn Name of each table as your DbTableName.
Following is dumy code please verify, i did't compile.

```
foreach(DataTable tbl in dataSet.Tables)
 {
       if(tbl.columns[0].name=="Person")
       {
        //your code to do with table Person
       }esle if(tbl.columns[0].name=="Car")
        //your code to do with table Car
       }
 }
```

Comment: I am using sqlServer, working in sql server. re structure for you mysql

Comment: Suppose we have more than thousand means it show the first columns of thousand records show the table name right

Comment: Its not a right way, but just a possible way. I search more for my own but finally i work to apply this approach. 2nd is just access datatable by their index, perhaps already you are accessing like ds.Tables[0] ..ds.Tables[1] .. ds.Tables[2]

Answer (score 0):

```
DataSet _ds=new DataSet();

DataTable _dtEmployee=new DataTable();

_dtEmployee=_ds.Tables["employee"];
```

or

```
_dtEmployee=ds.Tables[0];
```